# Как отследить появление клавиатуры?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, vue.js

Есть ли какие нибудь способы или библиотеки, помимо отслеживания изменения высоты и активности в input, чтобы отследить открыта ли у пользователя клавиатура или нет (на телефоне)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте событие `focus`. Когда пользователь нажимает на `<input>`, срабатывает это событие и появляется клавиатура.

```
$('#input').on('focus', () => {
    // ...
});
```

Когда фокус пропадает, срабатывает событие `blur` и клавиатура убирается.

```
$('#input').on('blur', () => {
    // ...
});
```